# How to convert image type using Wideimage library

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have a form where the user can upload an image and that image gets displayed on a webpage. I use the Wideimage library to resize the image and to rename the image. In the display code I have the name and type specified, but the problem is I don't know how to convert the image type in Wideimage so that it will display properly. I hope that makes sense.

Another option that would work is if I could somehow get the image type of the file name and then use that in the display code. I was looking at the `php function getimagesize()` but I couldn't quite get it working, that is, I had to run a bunch of if statements to see what type of image it was. It didn't seem practical.